# Generate random words from arraylist and check if they are in 2d array board game

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I need to generate 12 random words from the ArrayList
and add this word to 2d Array which is the board of the game, and this board is in another class WordSearch.

this is my code until now, please some help i can't understand how to make this.

```
public static void readWords(){
    WordSearch search = new WordSearch();
    List<Word> poolWords = new ArrayList<Word>();


    String[] wordsArray = {"play", "dream", "personal", "advice", "steal", "suspicious", "borrow", "image", "repeat", "enemy", 
                        "break", "selfish", "protester", "charity", "encounter", "discreetly", "effectively", "react", "respect", "depression",
                        "couch", "counsellor", "snatch", "judge", "appearance", "quiet", "ridiculous", "overjoyed", "antidote", "parademic",
                        "employment", "balance", "overwhelm", "relax", "flextime", "task", "daily", "realistic", "essential", "stressful",
                        "fixed", "key", "reward", "salary", "loan", "promotion", "value", "database", "schedule", "priority",};

                        
                        for(String word: wordsArray){
                            poolWords.add(new Word(word));
                        }
                        
                        Random rand = new Random();
                        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

                        System.out.println("How many words? max 12: ");
                        int maxWords = input.nextInt();
                        if(maxWords > 12){
                            System.out.println("i can generate only 12 words");
                        }
                        
                        
                        for(int i=0; i<maxWords; i++){
                            int random = rand.nextInt(poolWords.size());
                            Word randomWord = poolWords.get(random);
                            }
                            
                        }
```

Comment: Please show the result you expect and what your current code does.

Comment: What `"2d array board game"` are you talking about?  What is the definition of `Word`?

Comment: if you don't want any duplicate words, shuffle the `List` and select the first N words.

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, though you haven't provided any information about class WordSearch and how you add instances of Word to it.

Here is how to pick the random amount of words, though. Note that after each pick I remove that word from the "pool" so it can't be selected again.

Also note that it keeps asking the user for a number of words until that value is between 1 and 12 inclusive:

```
  public static void readWords(){
    WordSearch search = new WordSearch();
    List<Word> poolWords = new ArrayList<Word>();

    String[] wordsArray = {
      "play", "dream", "personal", "advice", "steal",
      "suspicious", "borrow", "image", "repeat", "enemy", 
      "break", "selfish", "protester", "charity", "encounter",
      "discreetly", "effectively", "react", "respect", "depression",
      "couch", "counsellor", "snatch", "judge", "appearance",
      "quiet", "ridiculous", "overjoyed", "antidote", "parademic",
      "employment", "balance", "overwhelm", "relax", "flextime",
      "task", "daily", "realistic", "essential", "stressful",
      "fixed", "key", "reward", "salary", "loan", "promotion",
      "value", "database", "schedule", "priority"
    };
                    
    for(String word: wordsArray){
        poolWords.add(new Word(word));
    }
    
    Random rand = new Random();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int maxWords;
    do {
      System.out.print("How many words? (max 12): ");  
      maxWords = input.nextInt();
    } while (maxWords<1 || maxWords>12);
        
    for(int i=0; i<maxWords; i++){
      int random = rand.nextInt(poolWords.size());
      Word randomWord = poolWords.get(random);
      poolWords.remove(random);
      
      // ... do something with "randomWord" ...
      // ... somehow adding it to "search" ...
      //search.add(randomWord); // <-- you haven't shown us how to use WordSearch!
    }   
  }
```